# jQuery .on() or click() not working inside in-app Facebook browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where I want to know if a quiz is started. I implemented this:

```
$('#choice_3_1_0').on('change', function () {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: trackgf.ajax_url,
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      action: 'tgf_form_started'
    },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

The problem here is, It works fine in all browsers. But the facebook in-app browser doesn't recognize it at all. Is there something I'm missing? Is there some browser compatibility issue here?

I have done lots of research found no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the cookies. For some reason the Facebook in app browser destroys the cookie and returns null. I am still inspecting but jQuery listeners have nothing to do with it.